# Copy file to dir using wildcards or regular expression in destination?

Tags: bash, clipboard

I want execute this `cp debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64/generic debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64/core2` but bash gives error in second `*`:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64/core2': No such file or directory
```

How can I copy one file in same dir but when other name without to change of dir nor to write the entire folder name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because the shell try to expand `*` glob character before executing the command, and the destination do not exist yet. One possibility to overcome this would be

```
cp debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64/generic "$(eval echo debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64)"/core2
```

More simply you can do:

```
( cd debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64/; cp generic core2 )
```

Or also

```
dir=debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64/
cp "$dir"/generic "$dir"/core2
```

Comment: Thanks, the second method is more simple but it would be: `( cd debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64/; cp generic core2; )`

Comment: Ah, ok. I would not spawn a subshell, but in such a case the `cd` remain in effect. I edit the answer

Comment: The first one, using eval, is dangerous. eval should be avoided at all cost. The last one won't work since glob expansion does not occur in variable assignments or inside quotes. I'd do `for f in debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64/generic; do cp "$f" "${f%/generic}/core2"; done`

Comment: @gheira: ok for `eval`, but the last one works imho, as long as the `*` is not quoted and the expansion gives only one string, as I think the user suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `debian.master/abi/2.6.38*` expands to multiple directories:

```
for dir in debian.master/abi/2.6.38*/amd64; do cp $dir/generic $dir/core2; done
```